# Write in an existing file with overwriting and append in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is it possible to delete a file before appending data in it?

```
  OPEN(61,file="file.txt",action='write',position='append')
  WRITE(61,*)f(i,j)
  CLOSE(61)
```

This will create file.txt and append the values f(i,j) in it. The whole set up is inside do loop. But If I run next time the same code, it starts appending from the last value it wrote before.
I wanted to completely remove the file content before it starts appending the data every time I run. Is it possible?

Here is one simple test program:

```
  program test
  double precision f
  dimension f(10,10,10)
  integer i,j,k
  character*500 ofile
  Do k=1,5
  do i=1,2
   do j=1,2
     f(i,j,k)= i+10d0*j+k
     WRITE(ofile,'(A,F4.2,A,F4.2,A)')'file',i*1d0,'_',j*1d0,'.dat'
     OPEN(61,file=ofile,action='write',position='append')
     WRITE(61,*)k,f(i,j,k)
   enddo
  enddo
  enddo
  CLOSE(61)
  stop
  end
```

In the first run the output is `cat file1.00_1.00.dat` :

```
       1   12.000000000000000
       2   13.000000000000000
       3   14.000000000000000
       4   15.000000000000000
       5   16.000000000000000
```

In the second run it starts appending in the last again `cat file1.00_1.00.dat`:

```
       1   12.000000000000000     
       2   13.000000000000000     
       3   14.000000000000000     
       4   15.000000000000000     
       5   16.000000000000000     
       1   12.000000000000000     
       2   13.000000000000000     
       3   14.000000000000000     
       4   15.000000000000000     
       5   16.000000000000000
```

I want to avoid the second case. Everytime I run, it should give without deleting the file before run,

```
       1   12.000000000000000
       2   13.000000000000000
       3   14.000000000000000
       4   15.000000000000000
       5   16.000000000000000
```

Note: I have to open the file inside do loop to format file name with do loop syntax. 
One easy solution is to remove all the output files everytime before run.

Comment: Do you mean _replace_?  But you could also position at the start, so is there a reason you need to choose `append `?

Comment: just remove the `position='append'`, default is to overwrite.

Comment: @francescalus The reason for append is to write in the same file all f(i,j) as the do loop i,j goes on .  Basically I want to stop the code and run again and then it should write removing everything it was written before.

Comment: @agentp, append is needed as the whole thing is inside do loop and I want to write all f(i,j) in a single file.

Comment: the `open` and `close` must be outside the loop.  Show more of the code if you are still having trouble.

Comment: You mean you open, close and reopen many times in a loop?  Don't do that, open once at start.

Comment: Please see my problem in the edited question.

Comment: see what happens if you just do `OPEN(61,file="file.txt")`

Comment: @agentp, this will work. However if I put OPEN inside the do loop it will not as it will reopen everytime. For that reason I had to use append to write in a single file. However if I run many times it continues appending instead of freshly writing on a file.

Comment: Is your goal to write the contents of the array `f` at several different points in your code, and each time you want to start from the beginning of the file?

Comment: Basically I want to write all values of f in a single file. In the example it will give the number  11.000000000000000 21.000000000000000 12.000000000000000 22.000000000000000. If I run again without deleting the output file, it starts appending in the old file again. I wanted that everytime I run it should give 11 21 12  22. Not 11 21 12 22 11 21etc.

Comment: Are you running the program multiple times, and each time you want to overwrite the file, or are you attempting to write to the file more than once within the same program?

Comment: do not open the file inside the loop.  You are making a really simple thing complicated.  FYI "position=append" is a very rare thing to ever use.

Comment: @MattP , yes that is correct. I am running multiple times and each time I want to over write the file.

Comment: Then the solution has already been given. Don't use `append`, open the file once at the beginning of your program.

Comment: @agentp I am also first time using "append". The main reason is in my program I have to open a file with name contains variable "i","j". This is the reason I can not OPEN the file outside do loop of i,j. Second thing is I want to write in this single file all the do loop repetition f(i,j). 
If I run the same code multiple times it keeps on appending instead of freshly starting.

Comment: you have nowhere previously mentioned anything about file names. You are opening exactly one file explicitly named "file.txt".  (I'm am now giving up on this.)

Comment: @agentp  yes that is true. I wanted to provide a simple example. And if you see my question, I was wondering about deleting the file before run. But somehow the discussion went to different direction. Anyway your help was useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the discussion you had with other users, I just think that (as mentioned) you are overcomplicating things here.

The following code (untested and using you formatting...) should give you what you want. If you want to do fancy things with the filename (which was a bit unclear in the discussion) then you may need to do something else.

```
  program test
  double precision f
  dimension f(10,10)
  integer i,j

  OPEN(61,file="file.txt",action='write',status='replace')
  do i=1,2
   do j=1,2
     f(i,j)= i+10d0*j
     WRITE(61,*) f(i,j)
   enddo
  enddo
  CLOSE(61)

  stop
  end
```

This will give you always the output you desire in `file.txt` at every run. So you open the file once (replacing any previous version), write the `f` as many time as the double loop iterates on (writing each record of `f` after the previous one in the same file, and I think here is where you are getting confused with `append`), and close the file.

**EDIT**

With the new example you posted the problem is now clear. This would have helped and avoided a lot of time if you could have explained in the original post.

A way to solve it is to add a condition inside the loop, where it checks if it is the first iteration of the loop or not (for each `k` value). Note also that the `k` loop needs to iterate the fastest (inner loop).

```
  program test
  double precision f
  dimension f(10,10,10)
  integer i,j,k
  character*500 ofile

  do i=1,2
   do j=1,2
     do k=1,5
       f(i,j,k)= i+10d0*j+k
       WRITE(ofile,'(A,F4.2,A,F4.2,A)')'file',i*1d0,'_',j*1d0,'.dat'
       if (k.eq.1) then
         OPEN(61,file=ofile,action='write',status='replace')
       else
         OPEN(61,file=ofile,action='write',position='append')
       end if
       WRITE(61,*)k,f(i,j,k)
       CLOSE(61)
     enddo
   enddo
  enddo
  stop
  end
```

If you want to stick to the idea of just removing the files before each run just add `call system('rm file*')` before starting the loops (this is for a Unix terminal).

Comment: thanks. This is not what I wanted. May be I am not clearly able to tell the problem. I want to open the file inside do loop.

In terms of mathematica I can tell the problem very easily.

1. output1 >> file.txt
   output2 >>> file.txt

vs
2. output1 >>>file.txt
    output2 >>>file.txt
The difference between these two is in case-1 everytime I run it will append freshly in file.txt, whereas in case-2 it will append on the old file.
Maybe I should start a new ticket clearly mentioning.

NB: One easy way out in fortran is to delete the file.txt everytime before I run.

Comment: But why do you need to open the file inside the loop exactly?

Comment: I am opening inside because my file name is formatted with the do loop syntax. Here is a complete code. If you run twice you will know the problem.
     `program test
      double precision f
      dimension f(10,10,10)
      integer i,j,k
      character*500 ofile
      Do k=1,10
      do i=1,2
       do j=1,2
         f(i,j,k)= i+10d0*j+k
         WRITE(ofile,'(A,F4.2,A,F4.2,A)')'file',i*1d0,'_',j*1d0,'.dat'
         OPEN(61,file=ofile,action='write',position='append')
         WRITE(61,*)k,f(i,j,k)
       enddo
      enddo
      enddo
      CLOSE(61)
      stop
      end`

Comment: Please see the example I have edited the main question.

Comment: Is this providing what you wanted?

Comment: Hi @b-fg, yeah it works. But somehow I feel in fortran this kind of simple things are inconveniently complex. Anyway thanks!

Comment: If you are comparing with a higher level language then probably yes (for I/O), but obviously those also have its not-so-good points.

Comment: Still not getting all the opens and closes, it will hose performance.  Are you humoring the fellow insisting on opening inside the loop?  A single open *outside* the `k` loop would do just fine.

Comment: True. It was to emphasise. If you add the replace one outside the k loop it will work just fine.